# How can I optimise this jQuery code to be more efficient?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar. I want it to switch classes (from 'navbar-dark' to 'navbar-light'), also adding the 'top-nav-collapse' class with additional styling to complement the light version of the navbar.
This behaviour should be triggered on scroll and on click.

The following code works, but it isn't very efficiently written. Please help me to optimize it!

```
// Switch the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('.navbar').offset().top > 50) {
    $('.fixed-top').addClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').removeClass('navbar-dark');
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo.png');
  } else {
    $('.fixed-top').removeClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').addClass('navbar-dark');
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo-diap.png');
  }
});

// Switch the navbar on click
$('.navbar-toggler:visible').click(function() {
  if($('.navbar-collapse:visible').length) {
    $('.fixed-top').removeClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').addClass('navbar-dark');
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo-diap.png');
  } else {
    $('.fixed-top').addClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').removeClass('navbar-dark');
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo.png');
  }
});
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There could be at least 2 possible ways, assuming you meant avoiding repeating code to be "more efficient":

Add 2 new functions, since the same 2 lines are code are duplicated twice, there could be a function for each set: (feel free to rename any suggestions to your preference)

```
// Switch the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('.navbar').offset().top > 50) {
    showLogo();
  } else {
    showOtherLogo();
  }
});

// Switch the navbar on click
$('.navbar-toggler:visible').click(function() {
  if($('.navbar-collapse:visible').length) {
    showOtherLogo();
  } else {
    showLogo();
  }
});

function showLogo() {
    $('.fixed-top').addClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').removeClass('navbar-dark');
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo.png');
}

function showOtherLogo() {
    $('.fixed-top').removeClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').addClass('navbar-dark');
    $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo-diap.png');
}
```

=====

Or maybe add one function that has the same handling as one if/else, and pass a parameter to make the difference of use.

```
// Switch the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($('.navbar').offset().top > 50) {
    toggleLogo(true);
  } else {
    toggleLogo(false);
  }
});

// Switch the navbar on click
$('.navbar-toggler:visible').click(function() {
  if($('.navbar-collapse:visible').length) {
    toggleLogo(false);
  } else {
    toggleLogo(true);
  }
});

function toggleLogo(mainLogo) {
    if (mainLogo)
      $('.fixed-top').addClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').removeClass('navbar-dark');
      $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo.png');
    } else {
      $('.fixed-top').removeClass('top-nav-collapse navbar-light').addClass('navbar-dark');
      $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src', '/assets/images/logo-diap.png');
    }
}
```

Either way, likely a matter of preference.